# SQL Server How to find the same person in

Tags: sql, sql-server

so, I have six columns(like name, id, SSN, Address and etc.) and if four of them are the same, then we can say those two are the same people. So, how to write a query to do that?

Comment: Add 6 case statements together where you set a value of 0 or 1  for each field based on whether a field matches.  Add the case statements together.  Keep records where the result is >= 4

Comment: Thats really Genius

Answer (score 0):

This will select the number of columns that are not the same for user x and user y. From here you can simply add a count, and modify the difference amount as you'd like.

```
SELECT ( p1.name <> u2.name )
     + ( p1.id   <> p2.id   )
     + ( p1.ssn  <> p2.ssn  )
     ...
     ..
     .
FROM
  peoples p1,
  peoples p2
WHERE p1.id = x
  AND p2.id = y
```